# SQL Server Timesheet Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a webapp for timesheet administration. I write a query to group all the time entry of an employee by week. And I also have to use paging. The query is already slow with something like 10 entry in database it took 2-3 second to run.

The query uses two table. 
TimeEntry representant a working day when the employee Start his work and when his done and the pause that he take in minute(TimeEntry.Pause).

I use this table to group by week and I do a sum by day(Monday, tuesday, etc...)
TimeType is just a kind of hour.

The second table representant how many time a company pay an employee for a given week.

Only the PK are indexed.

In the second image you can see the result here the column:

- FirstDayOfTheWeek
- LastDayOftheWeek
- SumByDayWeek for each
- HT give the total work time of the week
- HP give how many hour he has been paid for
- HB give how many hour he have in is time bank for this week
- HB TOT. give how many hour he have in is time bank till the beginning

I would like to have some tips to optimize this query as much as possible!

Here is the sql schema:

[image: schema]

Here is an example of the result:

[result http://s12.postimg.org/gbwc1wiqz/image.png](http://s12.postimg.org/gbwc1wiqz/image.png)

Here is the execution plan:

- [link](http://www.filetolink.com/fba6f17ac9)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TimesheetWeek_Employee_Search]
   @pPageNumber int,
   @pEmployeeID int
AS 
BEGIN

    SET  XACT_ABORT  ON

    SET  NOCOUNT  ON
    DECLARE @Count int
    DECLARE @PageCount int

    DECLARE @TmpTimesheetWeekEmployee TABLE(FirstDayOfWeek DateTime, CCQPaidHour int, CCQPaidMinute int, STAFFPaidHour int, STAFFPaidMinute int,
                                            CCQAdjustementHour int, CCQAdjustementMinute int, STAFFAdjustementHour int, STAFFAdjustementMinute int)
    Insert into @TmpTimesheetWeekEmployee(FirstDayOfWeek, CCQPaidHour, CCQPaidMinute, STAFFPaidHour, STAFFPaidMinute,
    CCQAdjustementHour, CCQAdjustementMinute, STAFFAdjustementHour, STAFFAdjustementMinute)
    select FirstDayOfWeek, CCQPaidHour, CCQPaidMinute, STAFFPaidHour, STAFFPaidMinute,
           CCQAdjustementHour, CCQAdjustementMinute, STAFFAdjustementHour, STAFFAdjustementMinute
    from TimesheetWeekEmployee
    where EmployeeID = @pEmployeeID

    DECLARE @TmpTimeEntry TABLE(ID int, TimesheetID int, StartTime DateTime, EndTime DateTime, [Pause] int, TimeTypeID int)
    Insert into @TmpTimeEntry(ID, TimesheetID, StartTime, EndTime, [Pause], TimeTypeID)
    select ID, TimesheetID, StartTime, EndTime, [Pause], TimeTypeID
    from TimeEntry
    where EmployeeID = @pEmployeeID

    select @Count = (select count(*) from (select 1 C
                                            from @TmpTimeEntry TimeEntry
                                           group by dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(StartTime), dbo.LastDayOfWeek(StartTime)) TE);
    select @PageCount = (case when @Count % 10 = 0 then @Count / 10 
                              when @Count < 10 then 1
                         else @Count / 10 + 1 end)

    select eID, CONVERT(char(10), TSW.FirstDayOfWeek ,126)FirstDayOfWeek, LastDayOfWeek,
           MinuteCCQ, LundiCCQ, MardiCCQ, MercrediCCQ, JeudiCCQ, VendrediCCQ, SamediCCQ,
           sum(coalesce(TotalCCQ,0)) TotalCCQBefore,
           MinuteSTAFF, LundiSTAFF, MardiSTAFF, MercrediSTAFF, JeudiSTAFF, VendrediSTAFF, SamediSTAFF,
           sum(coalesce(TotalSTAFF,0)) TotalSTAFFBefore,
           @pEmployeeID EmployeeID,
           @PageCount 'PageCount',
           coalesce(TWET.TotalCCQPaid, 0) 'TotalCCQPaid',
           coalesce(Twet.TotalSTAFFPaid, 0) 'TotalSTAFFPaid',
           coalesce(TWE.CCQPaid, 0) CCQPaid,
           coalesce(TWE.STAFFPaid, 0) STAFFPaid
    from (select  dbo.Encrypt( ROW_NUMBER() over(order by  dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(StartTime) desc) ) as 'eID',
            dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(StartTime) FirstDayOfWeek,
            CONVERT(char(10),dbo.LastDayOfWeek(StartTime)  ,126) LastDayOfWeek,
            Sum(case when TimeTypeID = 3 then DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause else 0 end) 'MinuteCCQ',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 1 and TimeTypeID = 3 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'LundiCCQ',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 2 and TimeTypeID = 3 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'MardiCCQ',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 3 and TimeTypeID = 3 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'MercrediCCQ',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 4 and TimeTypeID = 3 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'JeudiCCQ',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 5 and TimeTypeID = 3 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'VendrediCCQ',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 6 and TimeTypeID = 3 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'SamediCCQ',
            Sum(case when TimeTypeID = 4 then DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause else 0 end) 'MinuteSTAFF',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 1 and TimeTypeID = 4 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'LundiSTAFF',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 2 and TimeTypeID = 4 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'MardiSTAFF',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 3 and TimeTypeID = 4 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'MercrediSTAFF',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 4 and TimeTypeID = 4 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'JeudiSTAFF',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 5 and TimeTypeID = 4 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'VendrediSTAFF',
            Sum((case when DATEPART(dw,StartTime) = 6 and TimeTypeID = 4 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - Pause) else 0 end)) 'SamediSTAFF'
            from @TmpTimeEntry TimeEntry
            group by dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(StartTime), dbo.LastDayOfWeek(StartTime)) TSW
    left join (  select dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(StartTime) FirstDayOfWeek,
                        Sum((case when TimeTypeID = 3 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - [Pause]) else 0 end)) 'TotalCCQ',
                        Sum((case when TimeTypeID = 4 then (DATEDIFF(mi,StartTime,EndTime) - [Pause]) else 0 end)) 'TotalSTAFF'
                 from @TmpTimeEntry TimeEntry
                 group by dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(StartTime), dbo.LastDayOfWeek(StartTime)) TT 
    on TT.FirstDayOfWeek < TSW.FirstDayOfWeek
    left join (select E.FirstDayOfWeek,
                     sum(coalesce(twe.CCQPaidHour,0 )* 60 + coalesce(twe.CCQPaidMinute,0 )-(coalesce(twe.CCQAdjustementHour,0 )* 60 + coalesce(twe.CCQAdjustementMinute,0 ))) 'TotalCCQPaid',       
                     sum(coalesce(twe.STAFFPaidHour,0 ) * 60 + coalesce(twe.STAFFPaidMinute,0 )-(coalesce(twe.STAFFAdjustementHour,0 ) * 60 + coalesce(twe.STAFFAdjustementMinute,0 ))) 'TotalSTAFFPaid'
              from (select dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(StartTime) FirstDayOfWeek,
                           EmployeeID
                    from TimeEntry 
                    where EmployeeID = @pEmployeeID
                    group by dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(StartTime), EmployeeID) E
              left join @TmpTimesheetWeekEmployee twe on twe.FirstDayOfWeek < e.FirstDayOfWeek
              group by E.FirstDayOfWeek) as TWET
    on  TWET.FirstDayOfWeek = TSW.FirstDayOfWeek 
    left join (select   FirstDayOfWeek,
                        coalesce(CCQPaidHour,0 )* 60 + coalesce(CCQPaidMinute,0 ) 'CCQPaid',
                        coalesce(STAFFPaidHour,0 ) * 60 + coalesce(STAFFPaidMinute,0 ) 'STAFFPaid'
               from @TmpTimesheetWeekEmployee) as TWE
    on dbo.FirstDayOfWeek(TWE.FirstDayOfWeek) = TSW.FirstDayOfWeek
    GROUP BY TSW.FirstDayOfWeek, LastDayOfWeek, eID,
             MinuteCCQ, LundiCCQ, MardiCCQ, MercrediCCQ, JeudiCCQ, VendrediCCQ, SamediCCQ,
             MinuteSTAFF, LundiSTAFF, MardiSTAFF, MercrediSTAFF, JeudiSTAFF, VendrediSTAFF, SamediSTAFF, MinuteSTAFF,
             CCQPaid, STAFFPaid, TotalCCQPaid, TotalSTAFFPaid
    ORDER BY TSW.FirstDayOfWeek desc
    OFFSET (case when @pPageNumber > @PageCount then 1 
            else (@pPageNumber -1 ) * 10 end) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
END
```

Comment: The execution plan and info and existing indexing would be the most helpful thing to solve your problem.

Comment: And this would likely be better served on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I add a link to download the execution plan. The only indexed column are the PK. I will try to post my question on dba.stackechange.com

Comment: you added Estimated plan please post Actual plan

Comment: No this is the acual plan.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a good idea to calculate much of the stuff in insert?
I explain instead of doing something like
sum(coalesce(twe.CCQPaidHour,0 )* 60 + coalesce(twe.CCQPaidMinute,0 )-(coalesce(twe.CCQAdjustementHour,0 )* 60 + coalesce(twe.CCQAdjustementMinute,0 ))).
I simply wipe all those field and calculate it in the insert?